# Snake like animation on the rounded rectangle path

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-animation, ios-animations

I'm trying to implement an animation similar to what you can see on the image:
[image]

I'm using the Core Graphics and Core Animation with `UIBezierPath` to achieve this, but the problem seems to be with the start and the end of the `CGPath` (`strokeStart` always needs to be smaller than `strokeEnd` so the snake will not animate through the point where the path closes). After spending way too much time on this I begin to think that perhaps I'm using wrong tools for the job, any tips are welcome.

Here is the code sample I used for generating the image:

```
func animate() {
        let centerRectInRect = {(rect: CGRect, bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect in
            return CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x + ((bounds.width - rect.width) / 2.0),
                          y: bounds.origin.y + ((bounds.height - rect.height) / 2.0),
                          width: rect.width,
                          height: rect.height)
        }
        
        
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.frame = centerRectInRect(CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 200.0, height: 200.0), self.view.bounds)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        
        shapeLayer.strokeStart = 0.0
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.orange.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 12.0
        
        let rect = shapeLayer.bounds
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 16, height: 16))
        path.append(UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 16, height: 16)))
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

        let strokeStartAnim = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
        strokeStartAnim.values = [0, 1]
        strokeStartAnim.keyTimes = [0, 1]
        strokeStartAnim.duration = 12.0
        strokeStartAnim.beginTime = 1.0
        strokeStartAnim.repeatCount = .infinity
        strokeStartAnim.calculationMode = .paced
        
        let strokeEndAnim = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        strokeEndAnim.values = [0, 1]
        strokeEndAnim.keyTimes = [0, 1]
        strokeEndAnim.duration = 12.0
        strokeEndAnim.repeatCount = .infinity
        strokeEndAnim.calculationMode = .paced

        let groupAnim = CAAnimationGroup()
        groupAnim.animations = [strokeStartAnim, strokeEndAnim]
        groupAnim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        groupAnim.fillMode = .forwards
        groupAnim.duration = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
        shapeLayer.add(groupAnim, forKey: "AnimateSnake")
        
    }
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76516453/snake-like-animation-in-border-of-uiview-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to implement what I wanted. I don't think it's possible to do it with just one layer, so I used 2 layers and rotated the second layer 180 degrees, then synchronized the animations so that they overlap giving the effect that only one stroke is animated. Bonus - line cap can be selected from `CAShapeLayerLineCap`.

```
import UIKit

class RoundedRectActivityIndicator: UIView {
    private var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    private var progressLayer1: CAShapeLayer!
    private var progressLayer2: CAShapeLayer!
    
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat
    let lineWidth: CGFloat
    private(set) var segmentLength: CGFloat
    let lineCap: CAShapeLayerLineCap
    
    private var readyForDrawing = false
    private(set) var isAnimating = false
    
    private var strokeColor: UIColor
    private var strokeBackgroundColor: UIColor
    private var animationDuration: CFTimeInterval
    private var timeOffset: CFTimeInterval
    private var automaticStart: Bool
    
    required init(strokeColor: UIColor,
                  strokeBackgroundColor: UIColor = .clear,
                  cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.0,
                  lineWidth: CGFloat = 4.0,
                  lineCap: CAShapeLayerLineCap = .round,
                  segmentLength: CGFloat = 0.4,
                  duration: CFTimeInterval,
                  timeOffset: CFTimeInterval = 0.0,
                  automaticStart: Bool = true) {
        self.strokeColor = strokeColor
        self.strokeBackgroundColor = strokeBackgroundColor
        self.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        self.lineWidth = lineWidth
        self.lineCap = lineCap
        self.segmentLength = segmentLength
        self.animationDuration = duration
        self.timeOffset = timeOffset
        self.automaticStart = automaticStart
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if !readyForDrawing {
            firstTimeSetup()
        }
        if !isAnimating && automaticStart {
            startAnimating()
        }
    }
    
    private func firstTimeSetup() {
        shapeLayer = newShapeLayer(rectangle: bounds)
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeBackgroundColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeStart = 0
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 1
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        
        progressLayer1 = newShapeLayer(rectangle: bounds, lineCap: lineCap)
        progressLayer1.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor
        
        progressLayer2 = newShapeLayer(rectangle: bounds, lineCap: lineCap, rotation: 180)
        progressLayer2.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor
        
        readyForDrawing = true
    }
    
    private func newShapeLayer(rectangle: CGRect,
                               fillColor: UIColor = .clear,
                               lineCap: CAShapeLayerLineCap = .butt,
                               rotation: CGFloat = 0) -> CAShapeLayer {
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        let path = newPath(rectangle: rectangle, cornerRadius: cornerRadius, rotation: rotation)
        layer.path = path.cgPath
        layer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        layer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
        layer.lineCap = lineCap
        return layer
    }
    
    private func newPath(rectangle: CGRect, cornerRadius: CGFloat, rotation: CGFloat = 0) -> UIBezierPath {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rectangle, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
        path.rotate(degree: rotation)
        return path
    }

    func startAnimating() {
        isAnimating = true
        
        layer.addSublayer(progressLayer1)
        
        progressLayer2.strokeStart = 0
        progressLayer2.strokeEnd = 0
        layer.addSublayer(progressLayer2)
        
        let strokeEndAnimation1 = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        strokeEndAnimation1.values = [0, 1]
        strokeEndAnimation1.keyTimes = [0, 1]
        
        let strokeStartAnimation1 = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
        strokeStartAnimation1.values = [0, 1]
        strokeStartAnimation1.keyTimes = [0, 1]
        strokeStartAnimation1.beginTime = animationDuration * segmentLength
        
        let animationGroup1 = CAAnimationGroup()
        animationGroup1.animations = [strokeEndAnimation1, strokeStartAnimation1]
        animationGroup1.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        animationGroup1.duration = animationDuration
        animationGroup1.fillMode = .forwards
        animationGroup1.repeatCount = .infinity
        animationGroup1.timeOffset = timeOffset
        progressLayer1.add(animationGroup1, forKey: "animationGroup1")
        
        let strokeEndAnimation2 = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        strokeEndAnimation2.values = [0, 1]
        strokeEndAnimation2.keyTimes = [0, 1]
        
        let strokeStartAnimation2 = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
        strokeStartAnimation2.values = [0, 1]
        strokeStartAnimation2.keyTimes = [0, 1]
        strokeStartAnimation2.beginTime = animationDuration * segmentLength
        
        let animationGroup2 = CAAnimationGroup()
        animationGroup2.animations = [strokeEndAnimation2, strokeStartAnimation2]
        animationGroup2.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        animationGroup2.duration = animationDuration
        animationGroup2.fillMode = .forwards
        animationGroup2.repeatCount = .infinity
        animationGroup2.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + animationDuration / 2
        animationGroup2.timeOffset = timeOffset
        progressLayer2.add(animationGroup2, forKey: "animationGroup2")
    }

    func completeProgress() {
        progressLayer1.removeAllAnimations()
        progressLayer2.removeAllAnimations()
        progressLayer1.strokeStart = 0
        progressLayer1.strokeEnd = 1
    }
}

extension UIBezierPath {
    func rotate(degree: CGFloat) {
        let bounds: CGRect = self.cgPath.boundingBox
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        
        let radians = degree / 180.0 * .pi
        var transform: CGAffineTransform = .identity
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: center.x, y: center.y)
        transform = transform.rotated(by: radians)
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: -center.x, y: -center.y)
        self.apply(transform)
    }
}
```

You use it like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let segmentLenth = 0.4
        let duration: CFTimeInterval = 10
        let timeOffset: CFTimeInterval = segmentLenth * duration // or 0 if you don't mind it starting from the top left
        
        let indicator = RoundedRectActivityIndicator(strokeColor: .red,
                                                     strokeBackgroundColor: .orange.withAlphaComponent(0.2),
                                                     cornerRadius: 6,
                                                     lineWidth: 6,
                                                     segmentLength: segmentLenth,
                                                     duration: duration,
                                                     timeOffset: timeOffset)
        indicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(indicator)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            indicator.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 50),
            indicator.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -50),
            indicator.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 350),
            indicator.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -350)
        ])
        
//        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(8)) {
//            indicator.completeProgress()
//        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, if you want to try it out...

Use a 1/4 "pie wedge" as a mask for the bordered, rounded-corner shape layer, and rotate that pie wedge layer...

Note that the "jumping" seen here is only because the recording is repeating.

One-quarter "pie wedge" shape layer:

[image]

When set as a mask:

[image]

Sample view subclass:

```
class SnakeView: UIView {
    
    let snakeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let mskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
        layer.cornerRadius = 16
        layer.addSublayer(snakeLayer)
        
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        snakeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        snakeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        snakeLayer.lineWidth = 12.0

        snakeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 16).cgPath

        // create a 1/4th "pie wedge" shape
        //  use bounds.width as the radius, so it will cover the corners
        let pth = UIBezierPath()
        pth.move(to: bounds.center)
        pth.addArc(withCenter: bounds.center, radius: bounds.width, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: .pi * 0.5, clockwise: true)
        pth.close()
        
        mskLayer.path = pth.cgPath
        
        // any opaque color
        mskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        // so it will rotate at the center
        mskLayer.frame = bounds
        
        // mask the rounded-rect bordered shape layer
        snakeLayer.mask = mskLayer

        //layer.addSublayer(mskLayer)
    
        doAnim()
        
    }
    
    func doAnim() {
        
        // rotate the mask layer
        let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(Double.pi * 2)
        rotateAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        rotateAnimation.duration = 2.0
        rotateAnimation.repeatCount=Float.infinity
        mskLayer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not down-voting it but this is not what I'm looking for - it is too far from what you can see on the image I attached to my question. Also I can't see the images you attached.

Comment: @lawicko - it was just another approach that *might* have been an option... thought it was close, but oh well :)  (not sure why you couldn't see the images: https://imgur.com/a/GFUg5a3)

Comment: Clever. Some problems with the resulting animation: (1) It speeds up and slows down since the edges of the rectangle don't keep a consistent distance from the center of the rotation circle.  (2) The edge of the "snake" is at an angle rather than being squared off.