# Snake like gradient border animation in iOS

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui, uikit, border

I am trying to create snake like view border animation with gradient colour, see the image below.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76516453/snake-like-animation-in-border-of-uiview-swift) UIKit solution, but `CAGradientLayer` with `CAKeyframeAnimation` is not working. It is coming as background view not as a border.

Also I tried with SwiftUI, but the gradient animation is breaking for some dynamic height and width. Below is the SwiftUI code I have used:

```
struct GradientBorderAnimationView: View {
  @State var rotation:CGFloat = 0.0

  @State var width: CGFloat = 330
  @State var height: CGFloat = 100

  var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous)
            .frame(width: width*2, height: height*2)
            .foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.white, .white, .blue]),
                                            startPoint: .top,
                                            endPoint: .bottom))
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotation))
            .mask {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous)
                    .stroke(lineWidth: 3)
                    .frame(width: width, height: height)
            }
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea()
    .onAppear{
        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 4).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)){
            rotation = 360
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what is the issue in the above code or if anyone has any better solution, that also works. I am okay with `SwiftUI` and `UIKit` anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `AngularGradient` instead, like:

```
AngularGradient(colors: [.white, .white, .blue], center: .center)
```

So combined with your original code, it would be like:

[image: Demo]

Note that I've removed the manual size but you can play with properties to match your specific needs.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code.

Comment: The required code is **just that single line** I've included in the answer. The GIF image is just for the demo. @HangarRash

Comment: But the full demo requires the entire ContentView. I can't just type that one line to make the full demo work. Make it easy for people. If someone posted a question with a picture of their code then they would be asked to replace the picture with the actual code as text. Answers are the same way.

Comment: Other content of the view exist in the question already. Reposting redundant code is not preferred. Asking code in the question is for reproducing the issue. The answer only contains the minimal changes needed to fix the issue most of the times.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in another answer, it works better to use an `AngularGradient`. Also, instead of applying rotation to an underlying shape and then using a mask to show an outline, you can use `.stroke` to stroke the gradient at a changing angle.

However, the difficult bit is making it look like the snake is moving at a constant speed around the frame. Since the effect is based on an angle, the angle needs to change faster when the head of the snake is at the corners. One way to achieve this is to use an `Animatable` `ViewModifier`.

My understanding is that a `ViewModifier` can only be used to apply regular modifiers to a view. But in the case here, it is the angle of the gradient that needs modifying. So I ended up using the `ViewModifer` to apply an overlay consisting of a `RoundedRectangle` with stroked border.

The following example uses a brute-force approach to compute the angle based on the progress. I expect that someone with more mathematical ability could do it in far fewer lines of code.

```swift
struct SnakeBorder: ViewModifier, Animatable {

    let w: CGFloat
    let h: CGFloat
    private var progress: CGFloat

    private let perimeter: CGFloat
    private let oneEigth: CGFloat
    private let twoEigths: CGFloat
    private let threeEigths: CGFloat
    private let fourEigths: CGFloat
    private let fiveEigths: CGFloat
    private let sixEigths: CGFloat
    private let sevenEigths: CGFloat

    init(w: CGFloat, h: CGFloat, progress: CGFloat) {
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.progress = progress
        perimeter = (2 * w) + (2 * h)
        oneEigth = h / 2
        twoEigths = oneEigth + (w / 2)
        threeEigths = twoEigths + (w / 2)
        fourEigths = threeEigths + (h / 2)
        fiveEigths = fourEigths + (h / 2)
        sixEigths = fiveEigths + (w / 2)
        sevenEigths = sixEigths + (w / 2)
    }

    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { progress }
        set { progress = newValue }
    }

    private var angle: Angle {
        let completed = (progress * perimeter) / 100
        let radians: Double
        if completed < oneEigth {
            radians = atan2(completed, w / 2)
        } else if completed < twoEigths {
            let remainder = completed - oneEigth
            radians = (.pi / 2) - atan2((w / 2) - remainder, h / 2)
        } else if completed < threeEigths {
            let remainder = completed - twoEigths
            radians = (.pi / 2) + atan2(remainder, h / 2)
        } else if completed < fourEigths {
            let remainder = completed - threeEigths
            radians = .pi - atan2((h / 2) - remainder, w / 2)
        } else if completed < fiveEigths {
            let remainder = completed - fourEigths
            radians = .pi + atan2(remainder, w / 2)
        } else if completed < sixEigths {
            let remainder = completed - fiveEigths
            radians = ((.pi * 3) / 2) - atan2((w / 2) - remainder, h / 2)
        } else if completed < sevenEigths {
            let remainder = completed - sixEigths
            radians = ((.pi * 3) / 2) + atan2(remainder, h / 2)
        } else {
            let remainder = completed - sevenEigths
            radians = (2 * .pi) - atan2((h / 2) - remainder, w / 2)
        }
        return .radians(radians)
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .stroke(
                        AngularGradient(
                            stops: [
                                .init(color: .white, location: 0),
                                .init(color: .blue, location: 0.1),
                                .init(color: .blue, location: 0.4),
                                .init(color: .white, location: 0.5)
                            ],
                            center: .center,
                            angle: angle
                        ),
                        lineWidth: 5
                    )
            }
    }
}

struct GradientBorderAnimationView: View {

    let width: CGFloat = 330
    let height: CGFloat = 100
    @State var progress: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        Color.clear
            .frame(width: width, height: height)
            .modifier(SnakeBorder(w: width, h: height, progress: progress))
            .onAppear{
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 4).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)){
                    progress = 100
                }
            }
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

There would be scope to improve the solution in the following ways:

- The rounded corners could be taken into consideration when calculating the perimeter of the frame and when computing the angle for the gradient.
- The color stops could depend on the proximity to a corner, so that the stops are closer together when near a corner. This way, the length of the gradient could be made more consistent.